# Linux keys creation

Tags: linux, cryptography, embedded

Running openembedded linux kernel 2.6.32. 
I have patched the `mmc_sd` driver to support lock/unlock of cards. 
This functionality uses the linux kernel keys system. 
A new key type with the name `mmc` is created by the driver. 
When the driver needs to unlock a locked card, it makes a call to the request_key function with the following parameters:

```
Type="mmc", 
Description=SDcard CID,
Callout_info="password".
```

I have build the `keyctl` program, so it should be possible to create a key for the SD card from console or a script. 
The type and description is supported with the `keyctl add`, but it does not allow me to define the `callout_info`, so how do I create a key of this type?

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do here. Are you doing kernel programming? Or have you done that and are you now attempting do define a key?

Comment: I have done kernel programming, and i'm now trying to add a key for the sd-card. But I don't understand how to add a key, with the "password" callout_info.